# Writing to files in bundle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

If you scroll down to the section 'Writing to Files and URLs' at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459), would the path varaible have to be a file on disk?   Is it possible to write to a file in the bundle or must it always be deployed first?

Comment: Are you asking if you can write to a file stored in your application bundle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write files to the application bundle as much as you'd like.  Just get the path of the file through NSBundle's `pathForResource:ofType:` method and you can write to that file.  If you want just the directory of the bundle, use `resourcePath`.

You don't *want* to do this, though.  There are various reasons, but you'll break code signing, which is a big one.  You should use the established conventions instead (such as writing to Library:Application Support:Your App).

**EDIT:** For a (possibly) more convincing reason of not to do this...  When I was first learning Cocoa programming, I saved to the bundle because I didn't want to bother with the Library.  It got really annoying, though, because every time you make a change to your program, you lose all of your saved data/settings for that program (assuming you're not using `NSUserDefaults` for preferences).  I kept having to move it over from the old version to the new one.  By using the Library, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Plus, not _all_ users can write into files and directories in the application bundle. You really _shouldn't_ be writing into the app bundle at all.

Answer (score 5):

The bundle is on disk; it's just the ".app" directory. You should not write to files in this directory, however. While currently possible on Mac, it will break code signing. On iPhone, you already can't write into your own bundle, and we should expect to see this limitation in the future on Mac. You should write your application files into various directories under ~/Library or ~/Documents as appropriate. See the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for guidance.

Comment: Updated link to new location