# UILocalNotifications plays sound in Simulator but not on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm just trying to include a `UILocalNotification` into my newest app. Everything works well, but the sound doesn't do what I want.

I included a ringtone called "Electro.caf" the sound plays on my MacBook without problems. Even if I try it out in the iPhone Simulator as a Local Notification. But if I want to try it on my iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3.2) it doesn't work. It's not mute, volume is on maximum and I tried to delete the app, reinstall it and so on.

Is there anyone who figured out the same problem, or knows a solution?

Thanks mavrick3.

Comment: Check out @Matt Gallagher's answer on this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566301/iphone-some-sound-files-not-playing Also check out this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/converting-audio-to-caf-format-for-playback-on-iphone-using-openal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Simulator is case insensitive while the device is case sensitive. So make sure you write `Electro.caf` instead of `electro.caf`

Comment: The file is called "Electro.caf" and I try to set the soundName to "Electro.caf" so it should work, no?

Comment: Yes, it should. It was just a guess because everything else sounds okay.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347845/writing-to-files-in-bundle) by another user on Stack Overflow might help:

> The bundle is on disk; it's just the ".app" directory. You should not
>   write to files in this directory, however. While currently possible on
>   Mac, it will break code signing. On iPhone, you already can't write
>   into your own bundle, and we should expect to see this limitation in
>   the future on Mac. You should write your application files into
>   various directories under ~/Library or ~/Documents as appropriate.

Make sure than your sound length is less than 30 seconds and the sound file must be present into your main bundle

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong .caf file format.

To create a .caf file, use your iTunes.

iTunes -> preferences -> Import Settings -> import using : select AIFF encoder, 
make custom settings if you want
click OK, again OK

then select music from your library and click:
advanced -> create AIFF version
drag & drop new generated file on desktop, and change extension from .aif to .caf

that's it, you have .caf file that will work on your iPhone device